# [Linux Debian 8]: Driver Installation asks me to insert a disc

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia, data-cd

So I recently installed Debian 8 and am currently trying to get the software configured with my NVIDIA video card. The official Debian page instructed me to do this:

1. Add

   ```
   deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
   ```

   to the `/etc/apt/sources.list`.
2. Run

   ```
   # aptitude update
   ```

   and then run

   ```
   # aptitude -r install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') nvidia-kernel-dkms
   ```

I am not sure what I did wrong, because when I run the second command, it displays this message to me:

`0 packages upgraded, 16 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. Need to get 0 B/21.9 MB of archives. After unpacking 80.5 MB will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
Media change: Please insert the disc labeled 'Debian GNU/Linux 8.1.0 _Jessie _ - Official amd64 kde-CD Binary-1 20150606-14:19' into the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press [Enter].1`

I do not possess an optical drive so this creates a great issue for me.

I got the instructions from [here](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Debian_8_.22Jessie.22). 
See “Installation: Debian 8 'Jessie'”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is probably a line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (or in one of the files in `/etc/apt/sources.lists.d/`)  starting with

`deb cdrom ...`

Comment this line out and Debian won’t try to install packages from this disc.